# How to set a language for a column of table in a multi-language document?

Tags: languages, font-encodings

I want to make a table contains both English and Bengali text. Using `\setlanguage{english}`  I can ensure the computer modern font for English text. But, each time using this command is boring as I have many(about 50) cells with English text. In addition I have some columns with all cell are in English text.

So, if there is a solution that can help me to set the language as English for a column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{NikoshLightBAN}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.1cm,right=0.1cm,top=0.1cm,bottom=0.1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.13cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{1cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{1.3cm}|p{2.3cm}|}
\hline
\tiny{ক্রমিক নং} & ডিপার্টমেন্ট &  বর্ষ & PL শুরুর তারিখ & PL শেষের তারিখ & মোট PL (দিন) & পরীক্ষা শেষের তারিখ & ল্যাব শুরুর তারিখ & ল্যাবের আগে বন্ধ (দিন) & ল্যাব শেষের তারিখ\\
০১ & Chemistry & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
০২ & Chemistry & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
০৩ & Chemistry & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
০৪ & Chemistry & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
০৫ & Chemistry & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
০৭ & Chemistry & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
০৮ & Physics & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
০৯ & Physics & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Physics & 3nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১১ & Physics & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১২ & Physics & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১৩ & Math & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১৪ & Math & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১৫ & Math & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১৬ & Math & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১৭ & Math & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১৮ & Applied Math & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১৯ & Applied Math & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
২০ & Applied Math & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
২১ & Applied Math & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
২২ & Applied Math & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
২৩ & Botatny & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
২৪ & Botatny & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
২৫ & Botatny & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
২৬ & Botatny & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
২৭ & Botatny & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
২৮ & Pharmacy & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
২৯ & Pharmacy & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৩০ & Physicsn & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৩১ & Pharmacy & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৩২ & Pharmacy & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৩৩ & EEE & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৩৪ & EEE & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৩৫ & EEE & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৩৬ & EEE & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৩৭ & EEE & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৩৮ & CSE & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৩৯ & CSE & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৪০ & CSE & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৪১ & CSE & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৪২ & CSE & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৪৩ & ISRT & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৪৪ & ISRT & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৪৫ & ISRT & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৪৬ & ISRT & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৪৭ & ISRT & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৪৮ & Statistics & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৪৯ & Statistics & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৫০ & Statistics & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
৫১ & Statistics & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Statistics & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Nuclear & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Nuclear & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Nuclear & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Nuclear & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Nuclear & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Robotics & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Robotics & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Robotics & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Robotics & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Robotics & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Oceanography & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Oceanography & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Oceanography & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Oceanography & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Oceanography & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Zeology & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Zeology & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Zeology & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Zeology & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Zeology & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Zoology & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Zoology & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Zoology & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Zoology & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Zoology & MS &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Fisheries & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Fisheries & 2nd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Fisheries & 3rd &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Fisheries & 4th &&&&&&&\\
\hline
১০ & Fisheries & MS &&&&&&&\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\vspace*{1cm}
নিচের নমুনা অনুসারে লিখলে ভাল হয়\\ 

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.13cm}|p{5.6cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{2cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{5.6cm}|}
\hline
{\tiny  ক্রমিক} নং &  নাম &  রুম নং &  ডিপার্টমেন্ট &  বর্ষ & পূর্বে লাগানো সময় & জিম্মাদার সাথীর নাম\\
\hline
01 & ভাই মোঃ আব্দুল্লাহ & ১৬১০  & EEE & ২য় & ১ চিল্লা & ভাই মোঃ আরাফাত\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Form 2nd row of the column 2,3 all cell are in English text.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

something like this? You can revert the `begin{landscape} ..\end{landscape}` but it make
sense here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,longtable,pdflscape}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{NikoshLightBAN}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.1cm,right=0.1cm,top=0.1cm,bottom=0.1cm]{geometry}
\newcommand\MC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l|}{\selectlanguage{bengali}#1}}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\noindent
\begin{longtable}{
   |c|
    >{\selectlanguage{english}}l|
    >{\selectlanguage{english}}l|
    c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\tiny{ক্রমিক নং} & \MC{ডিপার্টমেন্ট} &  \MC{বর্ষ} 
             & PL শুরুর তারিখ & PL শেষের তারিখ & মোট PL (দিন) & পরীক্ষা শেষের 
    তারিখ & ল্যাব শুরুর তারিখ & ল্যাবের আগে বন্ধ (দিন) & ল্যাব শেষের তারিখ\\\hline
০১ & Chemistry & 1\textsuperscript{st} &&&&&&&\\\hline
        ০২ & Chemistry & 2nd &&&&&&&\\      \hline
        ০৩ & Chemistry & 3rd &&&&&&&\\      \hline
...\\
        ১০ & Fisheries & 3rd &&&&&&&\\      \hline
        ১০ & Fisheries & 4th &&&&&&&\\      \hline
        ১০ & Fisheries & MS &&&&&&&\\       \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

    \vspace*{1cm}
    নিচের নমুনা অনুসারে লিখলে ভাল হয়\\ 

    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.13cm}|p{5.6cm}|p{1.7cm}|p{2cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.4cm}|p{5.6cm}|}
        \hline
        {\tiny  ক্রমিক} নং &  নাম &  রুম নং &  ডিপার্টমেন্ট &  বর্ষ & পূর্বে লাগানো সময় & জিম্মাদার সাথীর নাম\\
        \hline
        01 & ভাই মোঃ আব্দুল্লাহ & ১৬১০  & EEE & ২য় & ১ চিল্লা & ভাই মোঃ আরাফাত\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can't use `p{}` to fixed the column width? if not I can't use this solution.

Comment: `\newcommand\MC[2]{\multicolumn{1}{p{#1}|}{\selectlanguage{bengali}#2}}` and then use `\MC{1.3cm}{...}`

Comment: You can edit your question with the requirement.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wvQ2q6Xm5y/ code

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.23 ...1cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{2.3cm}|}
                                                  \hline
?

Comment: `\usepackage{array}` as can be seen in my example!

Comment: https://ibb.co/iDbz0K output is not perfect. code https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/8q2b4PrdJY/