# Why verticle lines of the table are gone?

Tags: tables

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array,longtable,pdflscape}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{NikoshLightBAN}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.1cm,right=0.1cm,top=0.1cm,bottom=0.1cm]{geometry}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\newcommand\MC[2]{\multicolumn{1}{p{#1}|}{\selectlanguage{bengali}#2}}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{landscape}
\noindent
\begin{longtable}{
   |p{0.13cm}l|
    >{\selectlanguage{english}}l|
    >{\selectlanguage{english}}l|
    p{2.3cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{1.1cm}|p{2.3cm}|p{2.3cm}|}\hline
%\begin{tabular}{|p{0.13cm}|p{1.8cm}|p{0.9cm}|}
\tiny{ক্রমিক নং} & \MC{1.8cm}{ডিপার্টমেন্ট} &  \MC{0.9cm}{বর্ষ} & PL শুরুর তারিখ & PL শেষের তারিখ & মোট PL (দিন) & পরীক্ষা শেষের তারিখ & ল্যাবের আগে বন্ধ (দিন) & ল্যাব শুরুর তারিখ & ল্যাব শেষের তারিখ\\
\hline
01 & Chemistry & 1\textsuperscript{st} &13/09/18&13/10/18&30&1/12/18&9&10/12/18&20/12/18\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Related post [How to set a language for a column of table in a multi-language document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449729/how-to-set-a-language-for-a-column-of-table-in-a-multi-language-document)

Comment: @JohnKormylo Your comment is not clear to  me.

Comment: Right now I can't get past `\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{NikoshLightBAN}` using XeLaTeX.

Comment: @JohnKormylo You download and install this font easily from https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html in ttf format